# Fill view inside a Runnable class

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a class implementing runnable that made some task, then update some views:

```
public class DownloadPics implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //retrieve data
        fillView(data);
    }

    public void refreshView(ArrayList<Object> new_pics) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) ((Storico)context).findViewById(R.id.linearInsideScroll);

         View new_imageView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_element,
                null, false);
        //Build fill view


        linearLayout.addView(new_imageView);
    }
}
```

i Obtain an error when i call addView on refreshView method:

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You cannot update ui from a background thread.

Comment: if i put refreshView method inside the caller activity and i call it from run method, i obtain the same error

Comment: use asynctasj  instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

Updating ui from a background thread.

You cannot update ui from a background thread.  You can update ui from the ui thread.

Use `AsyncTask` makes it easier. You can do background computation in `doInBackground` and update ui in `onPostExecute`

Comment: @giozh why is that?? why not you can use if you do it properly

Comment: Because i'm donwloading a big amount of data, and i need to refresh views when data is available. With asynctask i need to wait that download finish

Comment: @giozh use a intent service if you are downloading takes long time. Asynctask is for a short duration. But you can't update ui from a non ui thread

Comment: then did you tried this way ? Thread for downloading, make a listener for when data is available, then it will trigger a method which will be refreshing the UI with new view...? just a thought... if you don't what to use asyntask.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method `runOnUiThread(Runnable action)`

**EDIT**

Use `ASyncTask` along with `runOnUiThread`

```
class download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
                    {
                        String message = "";
                        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() 
                        {
                            // what to do before background task
                            dialog.setTitle("Downloading");
                            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                            dialog.setMessage(message);
                            dialog.setCancelable(false);
                            dialog.show();
                        }

                        void updateItem(int i) 
                        {
                            class UpdateItem implements Runnable 
                            {
                                int pos;
                                UpdateItem(int i) { pos = i; }
                                public void run() 
                                {
                                         dialog.setMessage(message);
                                }
                            }
                            runOnUiThread(new UpdateItem(i));
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            downloadStuff();
                            i++
                            updateItem(i);

                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                            // what to do when background task is completed
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        };


                    };
                    new download().execute((Void[]) null);
```

Comment: I can't use it because thread do Network operations, so i get NetworkOnMainThread exception

Comment: Then like Raghunandan, you need to use `ASyncTask`. Stick this particular bit in a runnable and it run it on the Ui thread inside the `doInBackground` method if it needs to be in real time.

Comment: I have a function that does something similar. It only updates the waiting dialog (Downloading ? of ? jobs), but it's the same principle.

Comment: I've added it up there. Should be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference from a Handler that was created on the main thread (be sure that it is created on the main thead).

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

In the run() method of DownloadPics you would then use:

```
handler.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //update UI on main thread
    }
}
```